# scayt_ plugin stores lot of values in localstorage in chrome browser

Tags: ckeditor

[image]

A lot of values are stored in local storage session.I want to remove those values from the localstorage session.
Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable storing data in localStorage by using next option:

```
config.scayt_disableOptionsStorage = 'all'
```

And you can find more information about this option by following next link:
https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-scayt_disableOptionsStorage